Causality, compatibilism and the recognition of determinism
What I seem to know so far:
So in a deterministic universe, pretty much everything is laid out and this means there is no free-will if this was a deterministic universe, you and I would not have the freedom of deciding but being swayed by the contingent interactions of things including our minds, bodies and environments, you know the whole deterministic philosophy.
Now, recently, I heard about this interesting philosophy and also presented as in one of the questions on this site regarding compatibilism where even though the universe is deterministic there is this notion of free-will in a sense that we might feel like there are choices and so there legitimately are choices "from our perspective". I am not really fluent in compatibilism.
The question: "Does active recognition/awareness of being in a deterministic universe have any effect on the nature of outcomes?" "Does awareness affect determinism? If so, why and how?
Now, the meat of my question is what effects does the recognition or awareness of determinism has on the mind and our actions (i.e., on the deterministic nature of the universe or in particular our reality)? Are there different levels of consciousness that could let us experience "true free will"? Depending on our emotions or interactions of different properties of the mind to generate this weird meta-cognition or (a mindset) that could let us alter our behaviors so that they influence the outcomes and therefore making "true free-will" possible.
When I say "true free-will" what I mean is in the compatibilist point of view a more controlled choice or a more freer will, if you may? Are there any philosophy that put different degrees of "free-will"?

The question touches on the intersection of philosophy, physics, and psychology. To address it systematically:

Understanding Determinism
In a deterministic universe, all events are the inevitable result of prior causes, governed by laws of nature. If the universe is strictly deterministic, every thought, action, and event is already determined by prior states.

Role of Awareness in Determinism
Awareness, including the recognition of living in a deterministic universe, is itself a part of the deterministic chain. From this perspective:


Awareness does not "break" determinism but becomes another causally determined event.
Outcomes may appear to change when awareness leads to different behaviors, but these changes are still determined by prior causes, including the emergence of this awareness.
3. Can Awareness Affect Outcomes?
While awareness itself is determined, it could influence outcomes in the following ways:
Feedback Loops: Awareness can create a self-referential loop. For example, recognizing that one’s actions are determined could alter one’s behavior or decision-making processes, leading to different outcomes.
Behavioral Shifts: If awareness of determinism reduces anxiety about free will, a person may make calmer, more deliberate decisions. These new choices, though determined, result from the integration of new information (awareness).
4. Does Awareness Challenge Determinism?
Awareness does not negate determinism. Rather:
Awareness is simply a new variable in the deterministic equation.
The outcomes influenced by awareness still follow deterministic principles.
5. Implications for "Free Will"
The question also indirectly explores compatibilism (the idea that free will can coexist with determinism). If awareness leads to actions that align with a person's values or desires, some might argue that this constitutes "freedom" within determinism.
Why and How Awareness Affects Outcomes
Why: Awareness integrates new information into a system, altering subsequent thoughts and behaviors. For example, knowing you're in a deterministic system might encourage you to focus on optimizing actions within that system.
How: Awareness modifies internal states (e.g., beliefs, expectations) that influence external behaviors. These changes are part of the deterministic web.
In summary, while awareness of determinism does not undermine determinism, it can meaningfully shape outcomes by adding a new layer of causation.


what effects does the recognition or awareness of determinism has on the mind

This could also be asked as "What effect does the belief / faith in determinism/compatibilism on the mind?"
Compatibilism is the currently dominant philosophical thinking about mind as it removes all the need for "magic" that libertarian free will requires for reductionism. Quantum indeterminancies in the brain that do not just cause random actions but enable "agent causation" which nobody can describe in any scientific or logic terms.

that could let us alter our behaviors so that they influence the outcomes and therefore making "true free-will" possible.

Compatibilism is not some method to change people to be freer, it is just an attempt to describe how and why people already seem and feel free despite the challenges from monistic reductionism of the mind to brain states to atomic events.
A decision about whether a person has coffee or tea with your cake is not going to be influenced by whether this person believes in compatibilism or not.
When any neuron in a persons brain sends a signal that causes a finger of that person to touch a button, without compatibilism there is an issue of whether this neuron was caused to fire by prior events in the brain or by the person deciding it would be a great time for this single neuron to fire.
Compatibilism allows for both to be true without magic, the brain will act based on physical laws (which might be deterministic enough for the event to be inevitable within a short timespan) and not based on magical fairy dust, yet the agent created by this brain can also be described as being in control of the resulting action and responsible for the result.
Libertarian free will requires magic (or some other yet unfound physical force) to trigger the single neuron that moves the finger based on what a person wanted.
Compatibilism also solves many other issues such as at what stage the magic entered the biological world (do molecules have free will? viruses? bacteria? Plants? Fish? Insects? Mammals? does an embry have free will? A computer program?) To which Compatibilist can find reasonable and objective answers, whereas libertarians can only have subjective opinions.
As long as libertarian free will does not have a reductionist explanation, it is a philosophical dead-end upheld only by religious zealots and the like.

Decision-making is not magic nor has it anything to do with physics, quantum or classical. Decision-making is just a normal psychological process. We make lots of decisions every day, we decide which motor cortex neurons will fire and when. Causal physical processes cannot make decisions, mental processes cannot be reduced to  physical events. Libertarian free will does not need an explanation, it is the explanation for our voluntary actions.

That's your personal belief, not the one from philosophic literature or mainstream consent, and pushing your personal beliefs is against the policies of this site. Also you know that your comment will not make me change my answer, and comments are not for discussion.

If you know that my comment consists of only my personal beliefs, then you must know better. And your better knowledge says that decision-making is magic and an abnormal physical process. You know that we never make any decisions, they are all made by causal processes and magic.  I suggest you bring out some evidence supporting your "better" knowledge.

I rely on philosophic authority, such as the SEP, to which you have been repeatedly pointed, and which you still refuse to acknowledge as authoritative because you hold your own personal beliefs as more relevant than what philosophy has produced.

You are making no effort in proving that my comment is only a belief. Your accusation of me pushing beliefs is completely baseless, only a belief itself. Appealing to authorities does not help you as it is you who is pushing beliefs here.

Your answer and comment is enough proof onto itself to me and any other reader. If you cannot see that, I don't care.

@PerttiRuismäki. There's no way I can know for sure  why you're the most consistently down voted user on this stack, but if I had to guess, it's because you make highly controversial assertions without reference to literature.  I find many of your claims interesting, but you provide no reason for me to take them seriously.  This site encourages evidence, but you provide none.

@Futilitarian Your guess is wrong. I make no controversial assertions. I present only factual facts and actual definitions. I do not push any beliefs or worldviews. I am only showing the premises and letting everyone make their own conclusions. Only a true believer mistake facts for different beliefs.

@PerttiRuismäki. If you make no controversial assertions, you should be able to support them with evidence. Easily.

@Futilitarian: This was discussed with them before (several times), please do not encourage or engage them, or at least not in a comment thread to my answer.

@Futilitarian As I don't make any controversial assertions, I don't have to prove them. Facts are already proven.

I am beginning to understand what philosophy is all about. It is not at all about facts, it is all about opinions and especially whose opinions they are. All of my posts have been factually correct, they represent no opinions, beliefs or viewpoints. I am not doing any philosophy here, the reality checks I am offering are mistaken for opinions or beliefs and downvoted as such. My mistake is to post non-opinions, your mistake is to assume that they are opinions.

The opinions of Aristotle, Nietzsche, Schopenhauer, Locke, Sartre and so on ARE VERY much the subject of this site, not the "facts" of @PerttiRuismäki. Else this site would not be called philosophy.stackexchange.com, but perttiruismaki.stackexchange.com. it's a good thing you are beginning to understand what's obvious to everyone else.

@tkruse Even philosophers need to check the reality every now and then. Most questions here are about reality instead of some imaginary construct.

I suggest you check the reality of downvotes of your answers. Also if this site was about reality, it's name would be reality.stackexchange.com. it's not, go check the reality if the name of this site.

As the SEP article about "Free Will" shows there actually are a number of current philosophers who defend libertarian free will. -- I'd like to ask @PerttiRuismäki whether or not when humans make a decision any causal influences affect the deliberation process and the final decision making? If there are no causal influences whatsoever, then how is it that we can often make reliable predictions about other people's choices? If there are no causal influences at all how can even probabilistic predictions be made?

@mudskipper Naturally there are influences. Influences are just information we need to make informed choices. As both the influences and the resulting decision are just information (not physical events), the influence is not causal.

@PerttiRuismäki - Not sure I understand - Presumably the influence could be the perception of sth, right? And this perception could then be a non-causal influence on decision making. Does this mean all perception is like that -- a non-causal process? And if so, do other animals also have free will? (Surely, they have to make choices - for instance choosing who to mate with.)

There is also no shortage of people defending the ideas of alien sightings, angel visions, healing magnets and so on. Don't use my answer as a place for discussion. Use chat, or one of Perttis answers. It's not like those are hard to find.

@mudskipper All choices are made based on knowledge about past events, current situation and what we want from the future. Choices are not physical events, they cannot be caused or determined.

Reductionism is magic thinking too. It's the idea that atoms can come up with the theory of relativity.

we might feel like there are choices, and so there legitimately are choices "from our perspective".
YES.
If there are constraints on our behaviour that we are not aware of, it's like being locked in a big box that you can move around in. You have real, genuine free will ...inside the box. But if the box is big enough that you never touch the sides, that holodeck is identical to what you call "true free will." Even if you suspect it, you have no way of detecting whether you're really inside a box.
Suppose true free will exists. Nobody's constrained, Platonic ideal free will. You have a movie camera, and you record someone walking to the end of Gedankin Street, where he has to turn left or right. If he turns left, there's a hungry lion around the corner. If he turns right, there's a naked girl. He flips a coin and turns left.
Later, you watch the video over and over. Every time, the man makes the same choice. You watch him for the 9th time, urging him to turn right. But you know in advance what choice he's about to make.
Is his will free?
This whole answer is to induce you to watch a 1968 movie by The Monkees that deals with specifically this. Peter Tork and Jack Nicholson took LSD and sat in a Hollywood hotel room writing it all weekend. You can watch the whole thing free on youtube.
They don't play any music in this film. Instead, the four of them realize that they are fictional characters in a movie (the one you're watching), and they want to break out to exercise their free will. So they flub lines, destroy sets, and argue with the producer (Nicholson), who begs them to please, just stay in character and say what's in the script.
But no matter what they do, they discover that it's all scripted for the movie you're watching.
In this 3 minute scene, starting  here, they're trapped in a literal box, and logic doesn't seem to get them out. Then Peter has a revelation. It's the key. It's the answer. Unfortunately, nobody pays attention to it.
Increasingly frustrated, they become less jocular and more angry. They punch the other actors, break out of the studio, go on a city-wide rampage, and ultimately, kill people—including themselves — the ultimate act of freedom.
But no matter what they do, they find that it's all preplanned for the movie. In the last scene, the producer wheels a cart with their dead bodies into a studio locker, storing them until he needs them for his next film.
Really, their will was free the whole time. They found that they could do anything, but they wasted it trying to become free.
It's an amazing recursive tapestry they weave, and highly, highly metaphorical. The heads didn't watch it because they assumed it was going to be the wacky Monkeess from television, and the kids hated it because it wasn't wacky and they didn't play any music.
Many years ago, the box scene changed my life, for the better, and for ever.
Compatibilism  Is undoubtedly true. I hope you'll watch at least that one scene.


Aristotle, when he asked ‘what is the ultimate purpose of human
existence’ alluded to the fact that purpose was what he argued to be
‘happiness’.
https://positivepsychology.com/philosophy-of-happiness/#:~:text=Philosophers%20have%20been%20inquiring%20about,%E2%80%93%20%E2%80%9Cactivity%20expressing%20virtue%E2%80%9D.

It is not hard to imagine that, at some point in the future, humans abandoned bones and flash and moved into virtual/digital existence.
Then, our reality could be just a playground for their (people in the future) happiness.

Are there any philosophy that put different degrees of "free-will"?

Good question, but I don't think so. The shadows in the cave can be black and white.

In a hypothetical deterministic universe every event is completely determined by the previous event. This means that no event is even partially determined by anything else.
All concepts of free will or choice fall into the category of something else than the previous event. Therefore no free will in a deterministic universe.
Also feelings and illusions of choice fall into the same category of not the previous event. Therefore no feelings or illusions in a deterministic universe.
This is a description of a hypothetical deterministic universe; No actual deterministic universes are known to exist.

+1 Good explanation, although it seems that there are a lot of scientists and commonfolk actually hold a deterministic viewpoint and deem this universe to be deterministic. I guess, you can make the argument that we can't really know if this universe is deterministic or non-deterministic but I guess that is a different thing.

@Howwhye Determinism is not a viewpoint. Determinism is a simplified model of reality, a system different from reality by definition. The definition is the first paragraph of my answer.

The current mainstream majority believes in a somewhat non-deterministic universe and a compatibilist definition of free will that would also work (even better) with a fully-deterministic universe. Also that for most practical purposes, assuming a fully deterministic universe will yield the same results as including the known minor sources of potential indeterminancy. Tomorrows weather, the trajectory of rockets to Mars, the effectiveness of vaccines, and your insurance premiums will all be calculated based on totally deterministic models of the universe.

@tkruse Models may be deterministic and they may yield results that are accurate enough for most practical purposes. But we are here discussing the reality, not any simplified model of it.

I was talking to the OP

@PerttiRuismäki Well there are people that base their worldviews i.e., deterministic or non-deterministic or compatibilist based on these models so determinism is a viewpoint, I don't know where your disconnect is.

@Howwhye Reality is indeterministic. In a deterministic universe there could be no life, no beliefs, no imagination. It is logically impossible to believe that you live in a deterministic universe. You cannot believe in the absence of yourself and your beliefs. You cannot imagine the absence of imagination.
